# PHP: Show message to user e.g. Deleted

Tags: php

How can I show a message when say something is deleted and it appends a query string on the end of a url when it redirects so for example: `domain.com/?favor_trashed=294`

and it would then show a message like:

`<p>Favor has been successfully deleted</p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['favor_trashed'])) : ?>
    <p>Favor has been successfully deleted</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @alex LOL. That's about the most minimal answer I could provide... :D

Comment: @deceze Any reason you don't use `isset()`? In case the value is `NULL`?

Comment: @alex In this case `isset` is probably good enough, since the OP doesn't seem to be doing anything with the value. A GET parameter can't be `NULL` BTW. So in this case `!empty` only makes sure there's a value and the message doesn't pop up for `?favor_trashed`. Depends on the OP whether this is the intended behavior or not.

Comment: @alex I said *a GET parameter*, not *a value in the `$_GET` array*. :P

Answer (score 6):

Have a look into the Flash Messenger design pattern, the most common implementation being the one in the Zend Framework - [`Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger)

The basic idea is

- Pop a message onto a stack in session
- Redirect
- Display all messages on the stack
- Clear the stack from session

Comment: +1 also good, I'd prefer this then passing notifications in GET params.

Comment: +1 Flash messages are certainly great. Depends on the situation whether they're the way to go or simply overkill though. If you don't already have a certain infrastructure in place (mostly sessions), a GET parameter may be a good enough choice.